# Migrate Elasticsearch 2.4 to higher version along with Spring Framework 4.2.5 to Springboot 2.x. What will be best approach?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, migration

I want to upgrade my elasticsearch version & spring framework to Springboot 2.x version. Which elasticsearch & sprinbboot version should be used considering the spring-data-elasticsearch. I'm new to migrating application, would like to know the things that needs to taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any Elasticsearch migration before. But 2.4 is the very old version, I guess you need to rewrite the ingestion logic in the migration.

For your reference, we are using the following tech stack in the project:

- Spring boot: 2.3.x
- AWS Elasticsearch Service: version 7.1
- spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.10